# Not getting message from Redis publish function in Laravel

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis, laravel-5.8

I am publish message from Laravel and not getting in node js side. I am using Laravel 5.8.

Laravel Code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Redis;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function test(){
        $redis = Redis::connection();
        $test = $redis->publish('message', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));

        echo $test; // returned 0
        exit;
    }
}
```

NodeJs Code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(3000);
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('Starting...');
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

    redisClient.on('message', function(channel, data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);        
        io.emit('message', data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
Because I use redis.options.prefix.
function subscribe() callback $channel will replace prefix to ''.